# Running DHCP renew lease command from Docker Alpine Container

Tags: docker, dhcp

I am trying to manage my container host interface(one of the interface) from docker container. I am able to change ip address and assign static ip to interface but it looks like when i am flushing ip address in case of dhcp, I need to renew the lease using `dhclient eth1` which doesn't run inside container because there s no such package installed container. What would be best approach so I can renew lease ?

I am running container using `docker  run --net=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN  -v /etc/network/:/mnt/network -p 8080 -d ubuntu_network` command where `ubuntu_network` is my custom application. Any help would be appreciated.

I couldn't find any relevant document for this.

I should be able to renew lease from container to container host interfaces.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit late, but running `udhcpc` inside Alpine Linux seemed to work for me to get a new DHCP address.

Answer (score 1):

Within *Alpine Linux*, if the system is configured to obtain network configurations via DHCP, a DHCP refresh can be triggered with the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

via https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Configure_Networking#Activating_Changes_and_Testing_Connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `apt add dhclient` package on my container to run `dhclient` command from container so interface can send a query to DHCP server for renewing lease.

Comment: it's apk not apt